# Can I send a message to a certain IP+MAC addr to a machine if I get those addrs by ipconfig?

Tags: php, networking, ip

I'm new to web programming and currently working on LAMPP, I wanna have a try on writing some private msg app, and heard from some forums that I can send a msg to a certain machine once I get the correct IP+MAC addrs, but I don't quite understand where to start, **should I rewrite the packet head files? If so , should it be transportation layer work or application layer?**

Comment: What if multiple users are on the same IP (e.g. NAT)? The 'private' message wouldn't be that private this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-thinking it greatly by going to the IP/MAC layer.

The normal way to do a private messaging app would be to just do something similar to what a browser chat app would do to keep things confidential. It connects to a central server (the web server) using SSL/TLS encryption and stores a message there. The recipient would connect in the same way to fetch the message.

In case you want to add encryption on top of that so that nothing stored on the server can be decrypted, you need some other way to distribute user generated keys (for example, the clients generate a local key and give the public key to the server, then the other users can ask the server for the user's public key)

The reason going to the IP/MAC layer makes no sense is that all messages sent will jump through multiple machines to get to the right place on the Internet, without encryption any of those machines can read the message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's still a point I can't understand quite well. Say if I really wanna try to send a msg to a certain IP+MAC addr user, regardless of others can view the msg in the mid-way or not, is that possible?

Comment: @genxium A MAC address is only useful if the computers talking are on the same LAN (like your home network for example) and won't be sent anywhere outside of that network, while an IP is usable over the Internet. A comparison would be talking in person (MAC) vs. talking on the phone (IP). In person you can talk to people in the room, while with the phone you can talk to anyone world wide including people in the same room. Using both at the same time doesn't really make sense or make things more secure.